# Playframework (Scala) custom exception handling

Tags: beginner, scala, error-handling

I am using `play framework` with `scala` and here is a scenario on which I would like to have your opinion.

Let's say I have 2 custom exceptions that I can throw, which are `EmailTaken` and `AuthFail`. What I need to do here is, whenever any of these 2 exceptions happen, I need to return a `json` with 3 keys `success`, `errorCode` and `message`, in case of all other exceptions let `Play`'s default error handling take charge. Now for all custom exceptions `success` will always be `false`, each exception would have a unique `errorCode` integer value and a unique `message` string both of which remain fixed for a particular exception.

Now I saw people using `case class`(they can be pattern matched) or `class`(saw some java examples) for exception but I didn't see the point of creating them because for any particular exception I don't see the point of creating more than 1 object because its attributes don't have to be changed (I could create a `case class` with all default parameters but why?). So I created an `object` for each exception and then I throw that exception object in the controller and then in the `Global` object I rely on the `getCause` of the exception.

```
// custom exceptions code

trait AppException extends Exception {

  val success = false
  def errorCode: Int
  def message: String

  override def fillInStackTrace(): Throwable = {
    this
  }
}

object EmailTaken extends AppException {
  val errorCode = 1
  val message = "email already used"
}


object AuthFail extends AppException {
  val errorCode = 2
  val message = "id/password dont match"
}

// in Play's controller

object Application extends Controller {
def test = Action {
    throw EmailTaken
    Ok("Test Page")
  }
}

// in Play's Global object

object Global extends GlobalSettings {

  override def onError(request: RequestHeader, ex: Throwable) = {
    ex.getCause match {                
      case c: AppException =>     // a known custom exception
        Future.successful(InternalServerError(
          Json.toJson(Json.obj(
            "success"-> c.success,
            "message"-> c.message,
            "errorCode"-> c.errorCode
          ))
        ))
      case _ =>
        super.onError(request, ex)
    }
  }
}
```

I understand that if `AuthFail` was A `case class` I would have returned `new AuthFail()` and pattern matched on that exception object. Also, I could have used `isInstanceOf[AppException]` to check for custom exceptions. But are there any problems with this approach? Also, what are the other good approaches I can take? I don't have much experience with Scala or Java.

Answer (score 1):

You are right to not create classes for `AuthFail` and `EmailTaken`.
These really sense as *instances*, rather than classes,
as they are special cases of `AppException`.

For example if `AppException` was a class, then `AuthFail` and `EmailTaken` would be best as instances of that class:

```
class AppException(val errorCode: Int, val message: String) extends Exception {
  val success = false
}

val emailTaken = new AppException(1, "email already used")

val authFail = new AppException(2, "id/password dont match")
```

However,
if they are instances,
then you would need to pass them around in the code where they might be needed.
Another alternative is to make them objects,
so you can easily import them and use them where needed:

```
object EmailTaken extends AppException(1, "email already used")

object AuthFail extends AppException(2, "id/password dont match")
```

Your approach using a trait for `AppException` instead of a class seems fine too, but I'm fairly new to Scala myself.
Using a class like I did above seems shorter, so I would prefer it.

As for using case classes (or case objects),
in the posted code I don't see a need:
it seems that you don't need to differentiate the different cases.
If all of these cases can be handled as an `AppException` and result in an `InternalServerError`,
then there's no need to implement more.

Finally:

> I could have used `isInstanceOf[AppException]` to check for custom exceptions. But are there any problems with this approach?

Don't do that. It's recommended to avoid `isInstanceOf` as much as possible.
The alternative is using polymorphism or pattern matching.
In your case, you don't actually need any of this.
You have simple instances of `AppException`:
all your cases behave the same way,
their only difference is in parameters, not in behavior.

Comment: One of my concern was using `getCause` of the exception. I haven't seen it being used anywhere till now. Can the pattern match on `getCause` be unreliable sometimes?